# Filter on a specified column and check for blank if there are blank cells then deletes the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to macro... I want the macro to filter on a specific column named "Container" and check for any blank cells if there are any blank cells then it should delete the entire row. My below codes just hangs the whole excel its not working.

My COdes: -

```
Dim tst As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim colNumber As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rows As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim colHB As String
Dim ColumnLetter As String
Dim CCollum As Long

colHB = "Container"

Set tst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("POL")

lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
CCollum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To CCollum
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Cells(1, i).Value = colHB Then
        colNumber = i
        ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
        GoTo Continue
    End If
Next i
Continue:
  Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lRow)
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If (Len(tst.Cells(i, colNumber))) = 0 Then r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
Set tst = Nothing
```

[image: Column Named "Container"]

The column named container has few blank cells hence macro should filter on a column named container and then it should delete the whole/entire corresponding row, having blank cells.

[image: This is what the file looks like]

Comment: what is the error or it  has no error but didnot provide you your desired result?

Comment: I already told you to use auto filter ..You don't need any loop if you use autofilter..

Comment: there is no outcome from this code! it just runs and hangs

Comment: Can you share your file ..If you don't have any problem?

Comment: there is no option to upload the file however I have pasted one more screenshot of the file in the question above....

Comment: Okay..I need the file because after code i can test the code..You can upload it in your google drive/One drive/Dropbox and share the link...

Answer (score 0):

Please see script below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sRng As Range
Dim fRng As Range

Dim cel As Range

Dim tRow As Long
Dim fCol As Long


Sub foo()
    
    'setting wb as thisworkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'row 1 assigned into fRng(find range) object
    Set fRng = wb.Sheets("POL").Rows(1).Find(what:="Container", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    'gets fRng range object, and assigns its column property value into fCol variable
    fCol = fRng.Column
    

    'finding the last row for column 1, make sure you select a col that covers the whole data set, based on last row
    tRow = wb.Sheets("POL").Cells(Rows.Count, fCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'assigning range based on col index based on str search(fCol) + total row count (tRow) in sRng range object
    With wb.Sheets("POL")
    
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(1, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    
    End With
    
    'call sub deltR, the function does a filter based on range, string, and col number passed as argument.
    'passing arguments: range (sRng), delete anything not empty, on col#1 (sRng has only one range = columns("U:U" + tRow)
    Call deltR(sRng, "", 1)


End Sub





Private Sub deltR(ByRef sRng As Range, ByVal aStr As String, ByVal f As Integer)

    'this sub procedure looks for a string (aStr) passed in (sRng) range object range, based on col number (f)
    With sRng

        .AutoFilter field:=f, Criteria1:=aStr
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    wb.Sheets("POL").AutoFilterMode = False

    Set sRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

PLEASE NOTE that the trow will count the last row in column that has "Container" as string.

Please let me know if the script works.